# Como pegar valor de um RadioButon dentro de um RadioGroup para salvar no banco

Tags: java, android, sqlite

queria saber como pego o valor de um RadioButton para salvá-lo no banco sqlite.
No exemplo abaixo o instrutor faz da seguinte maneira:

```
public class FormularioHelper {

private Aluno aluno;

public FormularioHelper(FormularioActivity activity) {
    campoNome = (EditText) activity.findViewById(R.id.formulario_nome);
    campoEndereco = (EditText) activity.findViewById(R.id.formulario_endereco);
    campoTelefone = (EditText) activity.findViewById(R.id.formulario_telefone);
    campoSite = (EditText) activity.findViewById(R.id.formulario_site);
    campoNota = (RatingBar) activity.findViewById(R.id.formulario_nota);
    campoFoto = (ImageView) activity.findViewById(R.id.formulario_foto);
    aluno = new Aluno();
}

public Aluno pegaAluno() {
    aluno.setNome(campoNome.getText().toString());
    aluno.setEndereco(campoEndereco.getText().toString());
    aluno.setTelefone(campoTelefone.getText().toString());
    aluno.setSite(campoSite.getText().toString());
    aluno.setNota(Double.valueOf(campoNota.getProgress()));
    aluno.setCaminhoFoto((String) campoFoto.getTag());
    return aluno;
}}
```

O meu esta parcialmente assim:

```
public class FormularioProcessoHelper {
    private ImageView ivCaminhoFoto;
    private Spinner spPromotores;
    private RadioButton rbFavoravel;
    private RadioButton rbDesfavoravel;
    private RadioGroup radioGroup;
    private EditText edtObservacao;
    private Button btnDataProcesso;

    private Processo processo;

    public FormularioProcessoHelper(FormularioProcessoActivity activity) {
        ivCaminhoFoto = (ImageView) activity.findViewById(R.id.iv_foto_selecionada);
        spPromotores = (Spinner) activity.findViewById(R.id.spinner_promotores);
        rbFavoravel = (RadioButton) activity.findViewById(R.id.posicao_judicial_favoravel);
        rbDesfavoravel = (RadioButton) activity.findViewById(R.id.posicao_judicial_desfavoravel);
        edtObservacao = (EditText) activity.findViewById(R.id.edt_observacao);
        btnDataProcesso = (Button) activity.findViewById(R.id.btn_data);

        processo = new Processo();
    }

    public Processo pegaProcessoPraCadastro() {
        Processo processo = new Processo();
        processo.setCaminhoFoto((String) ivCaminhoFoto.getTag());
        processo.setPosicao(radioGroup.); // AQUI, QUERIA PEGAR O VALOR DO RADIOBUTTON SELECIONADO
        processo.setPromotor(spPromotores.getSelectedItemPosition()); //AQUI --//-- SPINNER SELECIONADO
        processo.setDataProcesso(btnDataProcesso.PegarAData()); // AQUI --//-- A DATA SETADA PELO USUARIO
        processo.setObservacao(edtObservacao.getText().toString());
        return processo;
    }
}
```

O problema é, eu não achei os métodos para pegar esses valores. Tanto do Spinner quanto dos RadioButton's. As linhas comentadas é onde estão os erros!

Minha classe modelo Processo:

```
public class Processo implements Serializable {
    private Long id;
    private String caminhoFoto;
    private Usuario promotor;
    private String observacao;
    private String dataProcesso;
    private PosicaoJudiciario posicao;

    public Usuario getPromotor() {
        return promotor;
    }

    public void setPromotor(Usuario promotor) {
        this.promotor = promotor;
    }

    public String getObservacao() {
        return observacao;
    }

    public void setObservacao(String observacao) {
        this.observacao = observacao;
    }

    public String getDataProcesso() {
        return dataProcesso;
    }

    public void setDataProcesso(String dataProcesso) {
        this.dataProcesso = dataProcesso;
    }

    public PosicaoJudiciario getPosicao() {
        return posicao;
    }

    public void setPosicao(PosicaoJudiciario posicao) {
        this.posicao = posicao;
    }

    public String getCaminhoFoto() {
        return caminhoFoto;
    }

    public void setCaminhoFoto(String caminhoFoto) {
        this.caminhoFoto = caminhoFoto;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Nome: " + getPromotor();
    }
}
```

Minha classe modelo Usuario:

```
public class Usuario implements Serializable{

    private String nome;
    private String senha;
    private String email;
    private String matricula;

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getSenha() {
        return senha;
    }

    public void setSenha(String senha) {
        this.senha = senha;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getMatricula() {
        return matricula;
    }

    public void setMatricula(String matricula) {
        this.matricula = matricula;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Você precisa pegar o radio button pelo id , em seguida, obter o valor do texto desse botão. Tente este código abaixo.

```
RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.youradio);
String radiovalue =((RadioButton)findViewById(radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId())).getText().toString();
```

Rotina para salvar e carregar:

```
private PREF_RADIO_BUTTON = "PREF_RADIO_BUTTON"
private RADIO_BUTTON = "RADIO_BUTTON"

public static void saveSetting(Context context, String key, String value) {
        SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_RADIO_BUTTON, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mSharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(key, value);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public static String loadSetting(Context context, String key, String defvalue) {
        SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_RADIO_BUTTON, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return mSharedPreferences.getString(key, defvalue);
    }

   public static void saveRadioButton(Context context, String value) {
        saveSetting(context, RADIO_BUTTON, value);
    }

    public static String loadRadioButton(Context context) {
        return loadSetting(context, RADIO_BUTTON ,"");
    }
```

Salvando/carregando da preferencia:

```
saveRadioButton(getContext(),radiovalue);
loadRadioButton(getContext())
```

Comment: Fala Edson,  tudo bem?
Então, essa parte ajudou, mas eu queria saber como salvo no banco,  usando aquele método meu lá em cima.

Comment: No banco do dispositivo?Voce pode usar SharedPreferences.

Comment: Editei minha resposta, ve se te ajuda.

Comment: Voce quer salvar o objeto, a posição do radiogroup ou o valor selecionado?

Comment: Quero salvar o valor dele, pode ser tanto o ID ou o Texto dele.
Salvando no banco, ta de bom tamanho.

Comment: chegou a testar o exemplo que eu complementei a cima? ele salva no banco interno.

Answer (score 0):

Faz o seguinte, cria um campo no banco `parecerFavoravel BOOLEAN;` no banco e seta True para Favorável e False para desfavorável.

Declara um Listener no RadioGroup para capturar qualquer ação nele como o Exemplo:

```
radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
         @Override
         public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
             //Verifica qual RB foi selecionado
             if(checkedId == R.id.posicao_judicial_favoravel) {
                 //Radio favorável Selecionado!
                objeto.setParecerFavoravel(true);
             } else if(checkedId == R.id.posicao_judicial_desfavoravel) {
                 //Radio desfavorável Selecionado!
                objeto.setParecerFavoravel(false);
             }
         }

     });
```

Qualquer dúvida na captura do click no RadioGroup, verifica este site: https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/ui/radiogroup/android-radiogroup-example/

Dai só é mandar gravar o objeto no banco normalmente. Se esse parecer for do processo, cria esse campo no DTO do processo e na Tabela dele do banco.

Comment: Agora que vi que você já tem um cara no banco pra isso, deixa ele do tipo BOOLEAN e grava nele como mostrei acima.

Comment: Poderia postar a classe PosicaoJudiciario caso ela exista?

Comment: Fala Erivaldo, eu tirei essa classe PosicaoJudiciario, optei por usar uma String mesmo.